# Operator bitwise left shift

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the recommended approach for updating an object after creation with a stream of data? I would like to avoid using a number of SetXX methods.

Say I have a class that looks like this;

```
class Model
{
public:
  Model(int, double, std::string);
private:
  int a;
  double b;
  std::string c;
};
```

One approach to solving this was adding operator;

```
friend Model& operator<<(Model&, std::stringstream&)
```

The usage of the above code;

```
// create model
Model model(...);

// do stuff

// update model later
model << stream;
```

This approach compile and runs.

Just wondering if this is a good approach and if it has any flaws \ limitations? Notice that most example online using operator<< use it differently than what I am doing above.

Comment: The usual way to get information from a stream is the input (or *right* shift) operator `>>`, so you do e.g. `stream >> model`, the way you get input from any other stream like `std::cin`. Your way works, but it's unusual and will not be easy to understand or comprehend by others except yourself (and maybe not even yourself in a few months time). Can you please explain why you want it the opposite way of what it's normally done? What's the rationale?

Comment: If this is working code then the question is probably better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Definitely a good question, however it might be more suitable for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as it deals with working code which does not show an error.

Comment: Joachim: No real rationale, just did what felt natural. Your advice look good. Thank you.

Comment: Paul: Will do that next time. Did not know about that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to follow the same notation as in the standard library: use `operator>>` for input and return reference to the stream, not the `Model`. This way it will be more readable for the others (who are familiar with the standard library but not your notation), and it will allow for chained inputs:

```
friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & s, Model & m)
{
    m.data = ...
    return s;
}

Model m1, m2;
std::cin >> m1 >> m2;
```

As `std::istringstream` is derived from `std::istream`, this operator will work for it as well as all other input stream types.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider writing an `update` method that takes a stream instead of using the operator. The flaw with using the operator `<<` is, as you stated, that it's not usually used for that purpose, which will probably irritate everyone looking at your code that doesn't know how you implemented the operator. `stream >> model` is more commonly used, as stated in the comments.

Comment: I have no issue with setXX methods. In this context I wanted one method that did the updating and could determine whether to trigger a signal that other subscribe.

Comment: If I changed to using operator>>, would you still prefer using an update method? What is the rationale for that?

Comment: @Lars I would still prefer the update method. In my opinion `update` states more clearly what is done, rather than the more generic `>>`. This might be a personal preference (I have a Java background, which doesn't support operator overloading), though.